# No such interface supported error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017, setup-project, build-error, visual-studio-setup-proje

I am using VS 2017 (version 15.5.2) on Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.7.02556.

I have also installed the `'Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects'` extension (version 0.8.4).

Then, I added a new setup project and added the Primary output to the `File System\Application` Folder.

I rebuilt the primary project and then tried building the setup project which results in this error:

---

> 1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: SCDS, Configuration: Debug Any CPU -----
>  
>   1> SCDS -> C:\Users\Stephen\Source\Workspaces\SCDS\SCDS\bin\Debug\SCDS.exe
>   ------ Starting pre-build validation for project 'Setup1' ------ 
>   ------ Pre-build validation for project 'Setup1' completed ------ 
> 2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Setup1, Configuration: Debug
>   ------
>  Building file 'C:\Users\Stephen\Source\Workspaces\SCDS\Setup1\Debug\Setup1.msi'...
>  ERROR: No such interface supported  'No such interface supported'
>   ========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

---

I also tried repairing my VS 2017 installation but I still get the same results. Has anyone else experienced this issue? What is the solution?

**UPDATE:**
I was not able to get this to work by using the 'Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects' which was created by Microsoft.

For now, my solution was to install the 'Advanced Installer for Visual Studio 2017' extension (created by Caphyon) and create my Setup project with that.

**Another Update:**
I finally got it to work using JoeJ's [suggestion below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48255359/4012879) by uninstalling VS 2017 and reinstalling it as well as the `'Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects'` extension.

Comment: Maybe related https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/18629/no-such-interface-supported.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also experiencing this issue with VS 2017 15.5.3.  I reinstalled VS 2017 (15.5.3) and the Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects extension.  After the reinstall, the MSI builds without the 'No such interface supported' error.

Answer (score 2):

restart Visual Studio works for me.

Comment: This fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this issue is related to the Windows SDK install because there's overlap. Changes to the Windows SDK/Kit can sabotage some registration. Look for mergemod.dll on your system and see if there are none or multiple copies. Doing a regsvr32 on mergemod.dll sometimes fixes this error because it's become unregistered.  That may also be why a reinstall could fix the problem.